# SDL not found by CMake

Tags: 16.04, compiling, cmake, sdl

I am building `cmake` app that uses SDL. But this code says that SDL not found:

```
find_package(SDL)
find_package(SDL_mixer)
find_package(SDL_image)
find_package(SDL_ttf)
...
if( SDL_FOUND STREQUAL "YES" )
    MESSAGE( STATUS "SDL FOUND: " ${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR} " : " ${SDL_LIBRARY} )
    link_directories( ${SDL_LIBRARY} )
else( SDL_FOUND STREQUAL "NO" )
    MESSAGE( STATUS "SDL NOT FOUND: " ${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR} " : " ${SDL_LIBRARY} )
endif( SDL_FOUND STREQUAL "YES" )
```

Prints this strange message:

```
-- SDL NOT FOUND: /usr/include/SDL : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDLmain.a/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL.so-lpthread
```

As I checked, `/usr/include/SDL` exsist and contain all reuired headers, and library files (`.a` and `.so`) is at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. What is going wrong?

UPD: After replacing `STREQUAL` by simple boolean check I can see it:

```
-- SDL FOUND: /usr/include/SDL : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDLmain.a/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL.so-lpthread
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:55 (link_directories):
  This command specifies the relative path

    -lpthread

  as a link directory.

  Policy CMP0015 is not set: link_directories() treats paths relative to the
  source dir.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0015" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

But `make` failed:

```
fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Doesn't `FindSDL` simply return a boolean value, rather than a string? Have you tried just `if( SDL_FOUND )`? See for example [cmake-modules - FindSDL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindSDL.html)

Comment: @steeldriver It didn't stopped configuring, but `make` failed: `SDL.h not found`

Comment: Well - shouldn't you be adding the found dir to `include_directories`? See for example [How to properly add include directories with CMake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake). Really this is a question for [so] IMHO.